# Create pie chart, line chart, histogram of highchart's in pdf using java

Tags: javascript, java, charts, highcharts, itext

I have to create a PDF that has nice and clean charts almost like UI. I have used highchart library to generate pie chart, line chart and other type of charts in UI.
So far, I have found that I have to create HTML of those charts and then convert it to PDF. is it only way to do it or is there any better approach ?

Please note that values will be dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [Highcharts official export server](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) or set up your own. The latter is preferred if you're generating a lot of charts or if you have security/data privacy concerns.

If you choose to set up your own server, follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server).